# Data-bind link doesn't open web page in Ungerboeck

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a system called Ungerboeck to setup a web store. The app allows me to place custom HTML code inside a section called `<!--TOPPAGE-->`. This is code placed above their system navigation menu and the stores main content.

This is what a standard link looks like in the main stores content page.

```
<a class="readMore" data-bind="click: function() {runCode('openPage', 2232)}">Read More</a>
```

I tried to add this type of code to my custom bootstrap navigation but the link does not work.

I tried using the same code from the left-side navigation which the Ungerboeck system generates for the top navigation I made.

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: panelCss }" data-view="public/controls/NavigationLinks/NavigationLinks" class="ux-nav--link ws-Links-CurrentLinkTextColor ux-navLevel-1" data-active-view="true" style="">
<!-- ko if: hasChildren --><!-- /ko -->
<a class="menu-link ws-Links-LinkTextColor" data-bind="attr: { href: url, id: 'navLink' + sequence() }, css: { 'ws-Links-LinkTextColor': !lastClicked(), 'ws-Links-CurrentLinkTextColor': lastClicked(), isSelected: lastClicked()}, click: linkClicked, text: description" target="_blank" data-track="true" href="" id="navLink288">Show Information</a>
<!-- ko if: hasChildren --><!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

But when added to my navigation menu, the link refreshes the site.

**Question**

How can I add links to my navigation menu that can link to a page within my site?

Webpage: https://ecommerce.sourceoneevents.com/prod/app85.cshtml?aat=E0jDDZomlL5TBOB6hWHMAz5j7IJY9TtwYxMQnlnL0Y4%3d

Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/CookieFresh89/pen/KKMVLOm

**Update 1/20/2021 from Ungerboeck**

> After discussing with the team, I can confirm that embedding those
> “data-bind=….” snippets into the web skin won’t work for you or other
> ESC customers. The web skin HTML is not processed for Knockout
> bindings for security, complexity, and performance reasons. On top of
> that, we couldn’t make the “runCode….” snippets functional at the web
> skin level as that code is specific to the store pages themselves.
> Lastly, since the web skin loads before anything else and shows all
> the time, there would be many instances where a link such as this
> couldn’t work since the store, and thus the page to navigate to,
> hasn’t even loaded yet, like on the sign-in page.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but If you just need static links why can't you just use `<a href='your-link'></a>` in your bootstrap navigation?

Comment: @LS_ the system Ungerboeck doesn't work with regular links. If you click on any of the side navigation links, you will notice the URL doesn't change.

Comment: @AndrewH, so the native way to write <a> element doesn't work and writing it in the way used in the system using data-bind doesn't work too, is it correct? and is it possible to add your custom js code?

Comment: @Zac Correct, using either regular href="" or using their data-bind doesn't work. I have updated my question with a message from their dev team. I can use my own Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the post, it's clear that you can't use normal `<a href=''>` elements, and also can't use them with `data-bind`, which of course has a custom implementation internally in their system, so you can add your custom way to navigate as well,

you can try something different to not override anything from their side, also you don't need it to be complex like their example,

ex:

add `data-href` for your `<a>` elements, with the path/url as a value

```
    <a data-href="/some-path">Read More</a>
```

and then in your js:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('a[data-href]').forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        window.open(item.dataset.href, '_self');
      });
    });
```

Comment: If I click on one of the side links, the URL doesn't change. IDK how this would work when the URL never changes.